# Busca por parte de string no mongo pelo php?

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

Como fazer :

```
db.getCollection('Collection').find({“field”: /.*A.*/})
```

utlizando PHP MongoDB\BSON\Regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há segredo, vamos supor que temos esses registros:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afae5b338597ce11fc99dc0"), "nome" : "Maria da Silva" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afae5bd38597ce11fc99dc1"), "nome" : "Anderson de Souza" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afae5d238597ce11fc99dc2"), "nome" : "Aline Santos Soares" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afaf370af3f834caebe3c4a"), "nome" : "Thon de Souza" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afaf510af3f834caebe3c4b"), "nome" : "amanda de lima 43" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afaf687af3f834caebe3c4c"), "nome" : "4632 sem nome" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afaf7c8af3f834caebe3c4d"), "nome" : "76 joana silveira" }
```

Para buscar todos os registros que comecem com `X` letra, número e ou palavra, utiliza-se o caractere circunflexo ( *^* ) antes do termo chave:

```
new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['nome' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^\d') ]);
```

```
> 4632 sem nome
> 76 joana silveira
```

buscar todos os registros que comecem com `X` letra ou palavra em uppercase:

```
new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['nome' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^A') ]);
```

```
Anderson de Souza
Aline Santos Soares
```

para busca independente de estar uppercase ou lowercase, informe a flag:

```
new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['nome' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^a', 'i') ]);
```

```
> Anderson de Souza
> Aline Santos Soares
> amanda de lima 43
```

Para buscar que contenha `X` letra, número e ou palavra, informe somente o termo chave:

```
new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['nome' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('an') ]);
```

```
> Aline Santos Soares
> amanda de lima 43
> 76 joana silveira
```

---

```
new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['nome' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('\d') ]);
```

```
> amanda de lima 43
> 4632 sem nome
> 76 joana silveira
```

E por fim, para buscar todos os registros que terminem com `X` letra, número e ou palavra, utiliza-se o caractere cifrão ( *$* ) depois do termo chave:

```
new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['nome' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('s$') ]);
```

```
> Aline Santos Soares
```

Para mais informações, [*veja esse tutorial na documentação do MongoDB ( em Inglês)*](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#regular-expressions).